# Swal show loading property HTML

Tags: html, angular, sweetalert2, angular8

I'm using SWAL2 (Sweet Alert2) in order to show an alert, and I want to show a loading progress spinner, but for html there's no documentation to show just a loading spinner. There is a property `showLoaderOnConfirm`, which shows a loading spinner after you click a confirm button. I just want to show the loading spinner whenever the alert is displayed, and make it through html.

It happens something like this, when you click on Lookup: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#ajax-request

```
<button mat-button type="button" [disabled]="paymentModeForm.get('endpoint').value == ''" (click)="testConn.show()" color="primary">
        <mat-icon matPrefix>power</mat-icon>
        <span i18n="@@testConnButton">Test Connection</span>
</button>
<swal #testConn title="Testing connection..." text="Checking the connection to {{paymentMode?.paymentMode}}" [showLoaderOnConfirm]="true"></swal>
```

With .TS I can do it:

```
  async testConnection(): Promise<void> {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Auto close alert!',
      timer: 3000,
      onBeforeOpen: () => {
        Swal.showLoading()
      }
    })
  }
```

Docs: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#frameworks-integrations

Answer (score -1):

You could use the html descriptions available in sweet alert and display a loading gif inside there.

```
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Auto close alert!',
  timer: 3000,
  html:
    '<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/xTk9ZvMnbIiIew7IpW/giphy.gif">'
  })
```

Comment: That's not what I want :-(

Comment: This matches your description of showing the loader using html. You will have to edit your question to understand more clearly what you need then.